# How to send FTP commands without listing directory, or transferring files with curl?

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I'm trying to send some standard commands to a ProFTPD-Server and curl always sends the `LIST` command and the result of my commands is overwritten by the `LIST` response.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://domain.xyz:21");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, array('PWD'));
$result=curl_exec($curl);
```

The log file contains:

```
> PWD
< 257 "/" is the current directory
> PASV
* Connect data stream passively
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx).
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 39794
* Connected to xyz (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE A
< 200 Type set to A
> LIST
< 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
```

I want to get the "257 "/" is the current directory" line.

Update:
There's an option `CURLOPT_NOBODY`, which deactivates the `LIST` command, but I can't still get the response of the `PWD` command, even with `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST`.

I can't use PHP's FTP commands, because PHP on windows doesn't have the `ftp_ssl_connect` feature. Is there any other FTP library with TLS support and up/download progress handlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that curl is designed for tasks like this.

Having said that, you can hack it by enabling logging and parsing the response from the log.

```
function curl_ftp_command($curl, $command)
{
    // Create a temporary file for the log
    $tmpfile = tmpfile();
    // Make curl run our command before the actual operation, ...
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, array($command));
    // ... but do not do any operation at all
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    // Enable logging ...
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    // ... to the temporary file
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $tmpfile);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($result)
    {
        // Read the output
        fseek($tmpfile, 0);
        $output = stream_get_contents($tmpfile);

        // Find the request and its response in the output
        // Note that in some some cases (SYST command for example),
        // there can be a curl comment entry (*) between the request entry (>) and
        // the response entry (<)
        $pattern = "/> ".preg_quote($command)."\r?\n(?:\* [^\r\n]+\r?\n)*< (\d+ [^\r\n]*)\r?\n/i";
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $output, $matches))
        {
            trigger_error("Cannot find response to $command in curl log");
            $result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = $matches[1];
        }
    }

    // Remove the temporary file
    fclose($tmpfile);

    return $result;
}

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://domain.xyz:21");

echo curl_ftp_command($curl, "PWD");
```